# Idris2: Nested WITH clause

Tags: idris, idris2

##### My Code

My piece of code, i.e.:

```
equal_suffix: Eq a => List a -> List a -> List a
equal_suffix u v with (snocList u)
    equal_suffix _ _ | Empty = []
    equal_suffix _ v | (Snoc x xs snx) with (snocList v)
        equal_suffix _ _ | (Snoc x xs snx) | Empty = []
        equal_suffix _ _ | (Snoc x xs snx) | (Snoc y ys sny) = case x == y of
            False => []
            True => (equal_suffix xs ys | snx | sny) ++ [x]
```

does not type check, with compile yelling:

```
Error: With clause does not match parent

Hello:857:25--857:38
 853 | 
 854 | equal_suffix: Eq a => List a -> List a -> List a
 855 | equal_suffix u v with (snocList u)
 856 |     equal_suffix _ _ | Empty = []
 857 |     equal_suffix _ v | (Snoc x xs snx) with (snocList v)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

##### My Question(s)

My first question is:

**What does *parent* mean for a `with` clause in the context of Idris (Idris2 to be specific)?** (Edit1: Thanks to @joel I now understand)

And if the first question can't help me understand this:

**What is the problem with my code?** (Edit1: Original Final Question)

**What is the correct syntax of using nested `with` clause in Idris(2)?** (Edit1: A More Focused Question thanks to the reminder from the comment @Vega)

(Excuse my snake-cased Pythonic mind for the naming of the variables :D)

Edit1 (2022-05-09):
The question was closed because the original last question is not focused enough. I adjust my question hopefully to reopen this as I am still in trouble with the `with` clause still.

##### What I have tried

To add more details, I did try the @joel version myself independently, i.e., to only case-split after specifying all `with` statement:

```
func: input_type -> output_type
func input with (view1 input)
    func input | input_in_view1 with (view2 input)
        func input | input_in_view1 | input_in_view2 = ...
```

I also tried to make a tuple of the two views, i.e.,

```
func: input_type -> output_type
func input with (view1 input, view2 input)
    func input | (input_in_view1, input_in_view2) = ...
```

However, these two do not seem to work (the first leads to an `unsolved hole` error and the second non-covering error or non terminating type checking depending on how I case-split) .

##### Example from TDD by Edwin

This `equal_suffix` exercise is from TDD by Edwin. I was still stuck and stopped at exactly this exercise.

Here is an example in the book which I copy as follows:

```
isSuffix : Eq a => List a -> List a -> Bool
isSuffix input1 input2 with (snocList input1)
    isSuffix [] input2 | Empty = True
    isSuffix (xs ++ [x]) input2 | (Snoc rec) with (snocList input2)
        isSuffix (xs ++ [x]) [] | (Snoc rec) | Empty = False
        isSuffix (xs ++ [x]) (ys ++ [y]) | (Snoc rec) | (Snoc z) 
            = if x == y then isSuffix xs ys | xsrec | ysrec
                else False
```

where `snocList` is redefined in the book for educational purpose and `rec` might be just a typo of `xsrec` and `ysrec` respectively.

##### Recursing on `with` clause directly for the totality.

I did manage to make it work when changing the recursive call
`equal_suffix xs ys | snx | sny`
to
`equal_suffix xs ys`

However, according to the book P275, to make a totally defined function, we need to recurse on the `with` clause directly to tell compiler about the relation between the recursive calls, so I want the function to be defined by directly calling the `with` clause recursively.

Comment: SO question post should have one question at the time

Comment: @Vega one qu is a half-way point to fully answering the other. Seems reasonable to me

Comment: @Joel, _what is the problem with my code_ alone is enough reason to close for not being focused. You have enough rep to close vote

Comment: you can check it's total by putting `total` in front of the definition. In this case, `| sny` does _not_ appear to be necessary for totality

Comment: also note `isSuffix` from the book is for Idris 1 not Idris 2. The `rec` argument to `Snoc`, which iirc is only in Idris2, may be removing the need for `| sny`

Comment: having a look at the [updates required](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/typedd/typedd.html#chapter-10) for the book in Idris 2, `isSuffix` looks like a bad example "The recursive with application in Idris 1 probably shouldn’t have allowed this"

Answer (score 1):

Simplest fix: remove `| sny` in your final line. Apparently it's not needed.

"Parent" presumably means parent function call in the recursive loop.

Now as to why it doesn't compile with `| sny` ... my guess is your second view is only present in one branch of your pattern match, whereas it needs to be present in both if you're going to pass `sny` recursively in `equal_suffix xs ys | snx | sny`.

You might be able to get something like this to work

```hs
equal_suffix: Eq a => List a -> List a -> List a
equal_suffix u v with (snocList u)
  equal_suffix u v | su with (snocList v)
    equal_suffix [] _ | Empty | _ = []
    equal_suffix _ [] | _ | Empty = []
    equal_suffix (xs ++ [x]) (ys ++ [y]) | (Snoc x xs snx) | (Snoc y ys sny) =
      case x == y of
        False => []
        True => (equal_suffix xs ys | snx | sny) ++ [x]
```

but this particular example fails to compile with unsolved holes.

Comment: "Parent" in this error message refers to the definition above the currently-matched `with`. So `(Snoc x xs snx)` apparently doesn't match the preceding `with` clause.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :D. I tried to do this but get also the unsolved holes. I don't understand where the unsolved holes are (which I understand as an implicit argument that cannot be resolved by the compiler, but I don't see where it is).